# What is the best way to create tables for email campaigns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.1

I have table `email_sent` with fields:

- id
- user_id
- template_name
- sent_at
- opened clicks

And now I need to save data which was send for each email. I have several campaigns with differnt data. For example, campaign wich recommend call to english teacher, if user call to teacher until expire date service will return 10% of charge. So for each email I need to save teacher_id and expire date. I have serveral ways.

First to create table `call_discount` with fields: email_sent_id, teacher_id, expire.

Second to create table `email_sent_data` with fields: id, fieldname, value and table `email_sent_to_data` with fields: email_sent_data_id, email_sent_data. But I will have huge amount of data and it will be hard to make right indexies.

Third to create table `email_sent_data` with fields: id, teacher_id, expire. Add column `email_sent_data_id` to table `email_sent`. And if I have new campaing I will add new fields to `email_sent_data`.

I have postgresql 9.1. So I can't work with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, **Postgres 9.1** does not have [`json` / `jsonb` data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-json.html). But there is the additional module [**`hstore`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/hstore.html) providing the data type of the same name.

`hstore` has been in the core release since Postgres 8.3 (it's very mature). For just text data and no nesting it's just as good as `json`, if not better. (`jsonb` introduced some new candy.)

If you only have a few dozen of sparsely populated columns I would also consider wide rows with many columns just being NULL. NULL storage is very cheap in Postgres.

- [Many columns vs few tables - performance wise](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99174/many-columns-vs-few-tables-performance-wise/99179#99179)

You *could* also go with an EAV (Entity-attribute-value) design. Related answer discussing pitfalls:

- [Is there a name for this database structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

But consider upgrading to a current version of Postgres first. [Postgres 9.1 reaches EOL in Sept 2016.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)